# a problem on boundedness of a analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ be analytic. Suppose that $|f(1/n)|\leq
\frac{1}{n^{3/2}}$ for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Prove that $n^2f(1/n)$ is bounded.

---

I am unable to solve this problem. can I get some help?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $f$ is analytic, then for $z$ in a neighborhood of $0$,
$$
f(z)=a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+O(z^3)
$$
Suppose that
$$
|f(z)|\le|z|^{3/2}
$$
What does this say about $a_0$ and $a_1$?

---

**From Comments:**

Since $|f(1/n)|\le1/n^{3/2}$, we know that $f(0)=0$. Thus, $a_0=0$. Therefore, $g(z)=f(z)/z$ is analytic. Since $|g(1/n)|=|nf(1/n)|\le1/n^{1/2}$, we know that $g(0)=0$. Thus, $a_1=0$.

Since $a_0=a_1=0$, we have that $f(z)=a_2z^2+O(z^3)$. Thus, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^2f(1/n)=a_2$.

Comment: did not understand your hint.please explain slightly.thanks for your time.

Comment: @damini: Since $|f(1/n)|\le1/n^{3/2}$, we know that $f(0)=0$. Thus, $a_0=0$. Therefore, $g(z)=f(z)/z$ is analytic. Since $|g(1/n)|=|nf(1/n)|\le1/n^{1/2}$, we know that $g(0)=0$. Thus, $a_1=0$.

Comment: but this gives $|nf(1/n)|\le1/n^{1/2}$ bounded but in the question it is given that $n^2f(1/n)$ is bounded

Comment: @damini: spelling out the last of the work: since $a_0=a_1=0$, we have that $f(z)=a_2z^2+O(z^3)$. Thus, $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}n^2f(1/n)=a_2$.